# Check if character is letter in Delphi (Unicode)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, pascal

Are there pre-defined charsets in Delphi, to check if a character is a letter?

In Cocoa I use something like

```
if ([[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] characterIsMember:character])
```

I know I can do in Delphi

```
if c in ['A'..'Z'] then
```

but will this cover foreign accentuated characters like Á, À, Ú, É, ....?

What would be the most efficient way to check this in Delphi. I need to check if a string is fully composed with letters.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try using the [`Character.TCharacter.IsLetter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Character.TCharacter.IsLetter) or [`Character.IsLetter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Character.IsLetter) functions

Comment: This can only be part of the story because it does not account for surrogate pairs.

Comment: TCharacter is a class that was created to work with Unicode characters, UTF-16. IsLetter is a function declared in this class. It should handle basic characters and the characters listed in the question.

Answer (score 2):

On Rad Studio XE4 I am told that `TCharacter` is deprecated and to use [`System.Character.TCharHelper`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Character.TCharHelper) instead. It is a record helper that extends type `Char` with functions in method syntax. This means that I now add `System.Character` to my uses list and can then call e.g. `C.IsLetterOrDigit` where `C` is of type `Char`.